# Writing a script to filter out text reports based on given conditions and outputs desired values

Tags: regex, bash, shell, ag

I've long list of generated reports which I want to filter. The report is something like this:

```
Report Name
Report Date
Blah blah blah
Parameter1: 85.34%
Blah blah
Paramter2 FF_6
Parameter3: 345
Parameter4: value
blah blah
OutputVar1: 98.34%
OutputVar2: 345
blah blah 
Output Var3:
      45, 34, 178
blah blah
```

Now I'm trying to write a shell script which get my conditions (on desired parameters) and print the lines of desired output variables with the filename itself. To achieve this I'm using `ag` and `regex`. I'm trying writing a script like this which filter the reports for me and prints the desired lines:

```
#!/bin/sh
# Script Name: FilterResults
# Purpose: Search through report directory (txt files) and put the desired output from all files which have the condition. 
# Usage Example: 
#    FlterReports OutputPattern FilterCondition1 FilterCondition2 FilterCondition3

case "$#" in
    1)
        ag "$1" 
    ;;
    2)
        ag "$1" $(ag -l "$2")
    ;;
    3) 
        #ag "(?s)^(?=.*$2)(?=.*$3).*\n\K(?-s).*($1)"
        ag $1 $(ag -l "(?s)^(?=.*$2)(?=.*$3)")
    ;;
    4)
        ag $1 $(ag -l "(?s)^(?=.*$2)(?=.*$3)(?=.*$4)")
    ;;
esac
```

This script works somehow but I've problem with case 4 when I'm trying to match 3 words. Also another problem is **when the filter conditions doesn't give back any file and in this case the script prints the desired output value of all files (instead of not do anything).**

One complicated case example is this:

```
> FilterResults "(Accuracy:)|Fold:" "algName:.*RCPB" "Radius:.*8" "approach:.*DD_4"
```

"Accuracy" and "Fold" are the desired output to be put on the output. I also like to have the  matched file name as well which is the default behavior in ag. Using this pattern i.e. "Val1|Val2" will cause ag to print both containing line after filename which is what I want.

The script should work with across multi-line regex and also put no results when the given filtering condition is empty.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem with empty case is because `ag "Pattern" $()` will match any file since the $() is empty.

---

```
#!/bin/zsh
# Purpose: Search through report directory (txt files) and put the desired output from all files which have the condition. 
# Author: SdidS

case "$#" in
    1)
        ag "$1" 
    ;;
    2)
        LIST=$(ag -l "$2")
        # Check if the list is empty
        if [[ -z "$LIST" ]]
        then
            echo "Check your conditions, No mathced file were found"
        else
            ag "$1" $(ag -l "$2")
        fi
    ;;
    3) 
        LIST=$(ag -l "(?s)^(?=.*$2)(?=.*$3)")
        # Check if the list is empty
        if [[ -z "$LIST" ]]
        then
            echo "Check your conditions, No mathced file were found"
        else
            ag $1 $(ag -l "(?s)^(?=.*$2)(?=.*$3)")
        fi
    ;;
    4)
        LIST=$(ag -l "(?s)^(?=.*$2)(?=.*$3)(?=.*$4)")
        # Check if the list is empty
        if [[ -z "$LIST" ]]
        then
            echo "Check your conditions, No mathced file were found"
        else
            ag $1 $(ag -l "(?s)^(?=.*$2)(?=.*$3)(?=.*$4)")
        fi
    ;;
esac
```

---